# Autovivification and Javascript

Tags: javascript, autovivification

Does autovivification only have to do with "derefencing" undefined structures, because in JavaScript if you specify a index or a property that doesn't exist won't it dynamically create it?  But is this not autovivification because you must declare the underlying structure to first be an object or an array?

Comment: This is the sort of programming language specific question that belongs on [programmers.se].

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Namespacing is one area where autovivification might be handy in JavaScript.  Currently to "namespace" an object, you have to do this:

```
var foo = { bar: { baz: {} } };
foo.bar.baz.myValue = 1;
```

Were autovivification supported by JavaScript, the first line would not be necessary.  The ability to add arbitrary properties to objects in JavaScript is due to its being a dynamic language, but is not quite autovivification.

Answer (score 12):

ES6's `Proxy` can be used for implementing autovivification,

```
var tree = () => new Proxy({}, { get: (target, name) => name in target ? target[name] : target[name] = tree() });
```

Test:

```
var t = tree();
t.bar.baz.myValue = 1;
t.bar.baz.myValue
```