# Is there a library to support autovivification on Javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, object, autovivification

Is there anyway, either natively or through a library, to use autovivification on Javascript objects?

IE, assuming `foo` is an object with no properties, being able to just do `foo.bar.baz = 5` rather than needing `foo.bar = {}; foo.bar.baz = 5`.

Comment: Purely natively, I don't think so. `undefined` isn't extensible or changeable and that's about the only way I could think of doing it without passing it through a function.

Comment: No. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691395/autovivification-and-javascript

Comment: @Ibstr, that question, while referencing autovivification and JavaScript, is not asking the same thing I am.

Comment: @Snuffleupagus, thanks I didn't think there was a way to do it natively, but it is good to have some confirmation. You should make your comment into an answer.

Comment: To the people voting to close this question on the basis of duplication, this is not a duplicate of question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691395/autovivification-and-javascript, that question is asking about the nature of autovivification. I am asking if there is are any libraries to accomplish autovivification in Javascript. It is a completely different question which should be evident to anyone who actually reads rubixibuc's question. I've edited the question title to be clearer about what I am asking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do it exactly with the syntax you want. But as usual, in JS you can write your own function:

```
function set (obj,keys,val) {
    for (var i=0;i<keys.length;i++) {
        var k = keys[i];
        if (typeof obj[k] == 'undefined') {
            obj[k] = {};
        }
        obj = obj[k];
    }
    obj = val;
}
```

so now you can do this:

```
// as per you example:
set(foo,['bar','baz'],5);
```

without worrying if `bar` or `baz` are defined. If you don't like the `[..]` in the function call you can always iterate over the `arguments` object.

Comment: I'm setting dictionary values like set('dict_obj',[0,'User'],5).  But I cannot return the value I set using a call like "Console.log('dict_obj[0]['User']) I can't return the value 5.  Do you see any error with how I'm using this?

Comment: @ouonomos: You're doing it wrong, you're setting the value on the string `'dict_obj'` instead of the object `dict_obj`.

Comment: I apologize; I mistyped.  What I'm actually doing is:     lastposxns={};
    grpname=0;
    tempname='abc';
    ypos=5;    dict_set(lastposxns[grp,tempname],ypos);  where dict_set is the autoviv function.  But console.log(lastposxns[0]['abc']) doesn't return the value 5.

Comment: @ouonomos: Still wrong, in javascript, using the comma in a square bracket access operator (as opposed to square bracket array literal) is interpreted as a comma operator. So your code is equivalent to: `lastposxns[tempname]` which is incidentally undefined. Also, you're calling the function as `dict_set(undefined,ypos,undefined)`. The first undefined is because of the reason I mentioned, the second undefined is because you're not supplying the value. What this means is that you're trying to set the property named `5` (ypos) of undefined (lastposxns[tempname] which is lastposxns.abc)

Comment: @ouonomos: Correct syntax should be: `dict_set(lastposxns,[grpname,tempname],ypos)`

Answer (score 2):

Purely natively, I don't think so. `undefined` isn't extensible or changeable and that's about the only way I could imagine doing it without passing it through a function.

Answer (score 2):

I had a desire to do this, so I wrote [a package to handle it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autovivify).

```
% npm install autovivify
% node
> Av = require('autovivify')
> foo = new Av()
{}
> foo.bar.baz = 5
5
> foo
{ bar: { baz: 5 } }
>
```

It'll even do arrays with numeric subscripts:

```
> foo = new Av()
> foo.bar.baz[0] = 'hum'
> foo
{ bar: { baz: [ 'hum' ] } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use an eval-based solution. It's ugly, not recommended.

```
function av(xpr) {

    var res = "";
    var pos = 0;
    while (true) {

        var pos = xpr.indexOf("[",pos);
        if (pos == -1) break;
        var frag = xpr.substr(0,pos);
        pos++;

        res += "if (typeof(" + frag + ") != 'object') " + frag + " = {};\n";
    } // while

    return res + xpr;
} // av()


function main() {

    var a = {};
    a["keep"] = "yep";
    eval(av('a[1][1]["xx"] = "a11xx";   '));
    eval(av('a[1][2]["xx"] = "a12xx";   '));

    console.log(a);
} // main()
```

Answer (score 0):

@slebetman's code doesn't seem to work.  The last key should not be assigned an empty object, but rather the `val`.  This code worked:

```
function autoviv(obj,keys,val) {
  for (var i=0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var k = keys[i];
    if (typeof obj[k] === 'undefined') {
      if(i === keys.length-1) {
        obj[k] = val;
        return;
      }
      obj[k] = {};
    }
    obj = obj[k];
  }
}

foo = {}
autoviv(foo,['bar','baz'],5);
console.log(foo.bar.baz);
5
```

Comment: Hi Mark , i have doubt , is there any good method to capture screen shot using angular js , if yes could you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44602309/making-a-proper-image-capture-of-screen-using-jquery