# How to declare a nested Javascript object in one statement with variable keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is probably something that Ruby does better, but is there a better way to write this Javascript code (for React):

```
handleCellChange: function(rowIdx, prop, val) {
    var updateObj = {};
    updateObj.data = {};
    updateObj.data[rowIdx] = {};
    updateObj.data[rowIdx][prop] = { $set: val };

    var newState = React.addons.update(this.state, updateObj);
```

Comment: Does this do what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498330/is-there-a-library-to-support-autovivification-on-javascript-objects/13523176#13523176 ?

Comment: not quite -- the keys are variables, rather than constants.

Comment: Yes, look at that set function again - the keys can be variables: `set(foo,[data,rowIdx,prop],5)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In ES6 you can use computed property names:

```
updateObj = { data: { [rowIdx]: { [prop]: {$set: val} } } };
```

You can use this in Traceur or Firefox nightly, etc. (but not yet in node --harmony).

Here is a thing which will transpile this syntax for you: https://www.npmjs.org/package/es6-computed-property-keys.

For more information see http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:object_literals#object_literal_computed_property_keys. Also see "computed properties" item in http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#.

Comment: I still wish they'd gone with the fat arrow for this, instead of using it for arrow functions. That way the syntax would have not only been in line with Perl, Ruby, Erlang maps, and Julia, but even lined up nicely with Ruby 1.9+'s literal Symbol syntax:  `{ foo: 1 }` vs `{ foo => 1 }` would mean basically the same thing (except for string vs symbol) in both languages.  Ah, well.

Comment: Don't know the background for that decision, but I suppose there is some rationale for preserving the semantics of the colon, or avoiding a situation where what follows the property name (`:` vs. `=>`) changes its meaning from literal to expression.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting use of brackets (for my rubyist eyes).

Answer (score 1):

Javascript's object literal notation (pre-ES6) has no provision for variable keys.  You could reduce the number of assignments a bit, though:

```
handleCellChange: function(rowIdx, prop, val) {
  var updateObj = { data: {} };
  (updateObj.data[rowIdx] = {})[prop] = { $set: val };
```

You may or may not consider that any improvement  - more concise, but probably less readable.  I would wholeheartedly recommend that you add the nested `data` object to the initial assignment to `updateObj` (which should be declared with `var`, btw) as I did above.  However, using the result of the initialization of `data[rowIdx]` as a value that you then index on the same line is of rather more questionable value.